# Contrasts in ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

In R, I can simulate data from 3 groups:

```
data = data.frame(Group=factor(c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50),rep("C",50))), 
              Y=c(rnorm(50, 50, 0.5),rnorm(50, 100, 0.5),rnorm(50, 10, 0.5)))
```

The default contrast matrix is

```
  B  C
A 0  0
B 1  0
C 0  1
```

so the intercept will correspond to the estimate for group A, and the two coefficients will compare groups B and C to group A.

The following contrast matrix

```
-1/3 1/2
 2/3 0
-1/3 -1/2
```

which is obtainable using

```
contrasts = matrix(c(-1/3,2/3,-1/3,
                 1/2,0,-1/2),ncol=2,nrow=3)
```

compares 1) group B to the mean of groups A and C, and 2) group A to group C.

This sort of makes sense to me but then when seeing what is apparently the contrast matrix to compare 1) group A to the overall mean and 2) group B to the overall mean,

```
 1  0
-1  1
 0 -1
```

I get lost. I don't know mathematically what the contrast matrix is doing. Each column is a contrast; the first column has a 1 for entry A and a -1 for entry B; to me that compares group A to B, not group A to the overall mean. Can anyone explain this?